# Javascript Wait until text appear

Tags: javascript, wait

How to wait until some text on a page appear?
I am using this but it does not work:

```
function waitText() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML == "Some Text"){
        alert("text appears");
    }else{
        setTimeout(function() { waitText() }, 1000);
}
}
```

Comment: GetElementByTagName returns an array

Comment: @Homberto `getElementByTagName` is _undefined_ ;)

Comment: Had you checked your error console, you'd have seen the error message.  And "not works" is *never* enough info when asking for help.

Comment: Nothing happens. I have a page with a timer. When a timer is done it shows the text. That is why I need to wait until this timer done and show alert if the text appears. I am trying to use this script with Userscripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code,

- Firstly, we don't want to repeatedly set intervals - this will cause a cascade and ultimately freeze the thread which is not fun
- Second, *getElementByTagName* is not a method on `document`. You either have to index into item `0` of the result of `document.getElementsByTagName`, or use some other lookup such as `document.querySelector`

So an example of how you might do it follows

```
function waitForText(element, text, callback, freq) {
    if (!element || !callback || typeof text !== 'string')
        throw new TypeError('Bad value');
    var interval = window.setInterval(test, freq || 200);
    function test() {
        if (!element.parentNode) // node detached, don't hold onto this
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        if (element.textContent === text) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            callback.call(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
// say you want the first <p> in the DOM tree
var elm = document.querySelector('p');
// attach the condition
waitForText(elm, 'some text', () => console.log('Text appears'));
```

And in the future..

```
window.setTimeout(() => elm.textContent = 'some text', 6e3);
// wait 6 seconds..
// callback fires
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I have a page with a timer. When a timer is done it shows the text. That is why I need to wait until this timer done and show alert if the text appears. I am trying to use this script with Userscripts.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead of that dirty checking if you don't need to support legacy browsers.

```
var target = document.querySelector('p');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     [].every.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) { 
       if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent === text) { // optionally you can remove nodeType checking if you pass the text inside some element like div etc.
         console.log("text appeared");
         observer.disconnect();
         return false;
       }
       return true;
     });
  });   
});
observer.observe(target, { childList: true });
```

Comment: What happens here if _#text_ data is modified without adding/removing the node?

Comment: It's unlikely to work. It works when you set the value i.e. using textContent etc. on the parent, but not when the text node changes itself.